# How to have onClick interactions with specific text elements of a pdf rendered in React?

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I am rendering a PDF file in React using react-pdf.

I have a list of textItems that I want to highlight directly in the PDF and have onClick interactions with.

There are two problems:

- the TextRenderer renders text nodes by nodes, and sometimes a text item that needs to be highlighted is split in multiple nodes, which makes it super laborious to find and highlight. However this may be feasible with a lot of effort.
- biggest problem: using the TextRenderer, I can only output HTML strings, but no React Components, so I can't setup an onClick interaction with the highlighted items.

I thought about doing it with the coordinates of each text node and overlaying transparent views, but I can't be precise in the view's position and size.

I'm open to changing PDF rendering library.